# Account with conflicting name exists locally

Tags: linux

I was installing Docker CE on Red Hat.

I tried to add myself to the docker group

```
#-> usermod -aG docker sid
```

but got an error that the user does not exist. Not sure why I got this error in the first place. But anyway I did

```
#-> adduser sid
```

I did get this message when I ran above command

```
adduser: warning: the home directory already exists.
Not copying any file from skel directory into it.
```

The `usermod` worked after that. But now when I `ssh` into the machine, I get this warning which does not look nice.

```
Account with conflicting name (sid) exists locally
```

Can anyone explain what is going on and how to fix it? [This](https://serverfault.com/a/280671) link is saying to kill all processes owned by `sid` and I am not sure if that is the right solution.

Additional information in case its helpful. I can see

```
#-> grep sid /etc/group
docker:x:500:cht_agent,sid
sid:x:502:

#-> grep sid /etc/passwd
sid:x:502:502::/home/sid:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to manually delete the user from `/etc/passwd` which is a directory of local users in the system. So delete (requires `root` privileges):

```
sid:x:502:502::/home/sid:/bin/bash
```